Ploblem with tkz-euclide (plot of floor function)
I use a snippet found in tex.stackexchange. Unfortunately, the author did not provide a MWE. So I had to make one on my own.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % for \tkzInit and \tkzAxeXY

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Axes and grid
    \tkzInit[xmin = -5, xmax = 5, ymin = -5, ymax = 5]
    \tkzGrid[sub, subxstep=1, subystep=1] % Subgrid every 1 unit
    \tkzAxeXY % Draw axes
    
    % Floor function (blue)
    \draw[thick, domain=-5:5, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {int(\x)});
    \node[blue, below right] at (2,2) {$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$};
    
    % Ceiling function (red)
    \draw[thick, domain=-5:5, smooth, variable=\x, red] plot ({\x}, {int(\x)+1});
    \node[red, above left] at (2,3) {$g(x) = \lceil x \rceil$};
    
    % Nodes for dots on grid points
    \foreach \a in {-5,...,5}{
        \node [circle, draw, fill=none, line width=.5pt, color=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt] at (\a, \a) {};
        \node [circle, draw, fill, line width=.5pt, color=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt] at (\a + 1, \a) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}

The problem is that above code cannot be compiled correctly. I get the error message
! Undefined control sequence.
 \tkzAxeXY
l.12 \tkzAxeXY
% Draw axes
Any ideas? What is strange is the same code works correctly if the line \tkzAxeXY is commented. I guess therefore that it could be a tkz-euclide issue as installed in my pc (TeXmaker and MikTeX).

As mentioned in this post, you need to include the tkz-base package to use \tkzAxeXY command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-base,tkz-euclide} % for \tkzInit and \tkzAxeXY

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Axes and grid
    \tkzInit[xmin = -5, xmax = 5, ymin = -5, ymax = 5]
    \tkzGrid[sub, subxstep=1, subystep=1] % Subgrid every 1 unit
    \tkzAxeXY % Draw axes
    
    % Floor function (blue)
    \draw[thick, domain=-5:5, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {int(\x)});
    \node[blue, below right] at (2,2) {$f(x) = \lfloor x \rfloor$};
    
    % Ceiling function (red)
    \draw[thick, domain=-5:5, smooth, variable=\x, red] plot ({\x}, {int(\x)+1});
    \node[red, above left] at (2,3) {$g(x) = \lceil x \rceil$};
    
    % Nodes for dots on grid points
    \foreach \a in {-5,...,5}{
        \node [circle, draw, fill=none, line width=.5pt, color=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt] at (\a, \a) {};
        \node [circle, draw, fill, line width=.5pt, color=blue, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=3pt] at (\a + 1, \a) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Given that the whole problem was caused by an answer without a MWE, wouldn't it make sense to include one in your answer?

You are right; I have updated my answer.
